# WxPython - Opening a new window with a button

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I'm creating an Interface, and I need to open a new window with a click of a button.
So I've created the Main Window, and I've created all the buttons, and created the new Window under a class. I'm not entirely sure if that is needed but I'll include that piece of information too. New to python so sorry if It's full of mistakes.

If someone could also answer how to hide the Main Menu when opening another window, that would be great. Cheers.

```
import wxversion
wxversion.select("2.8")
import wx

class App(wx.App):

def OnInit(self):
   frame = window()
   frame.Show()
   self.SetTopWindow(frame)
   return True

class window(wx.Frame):

title = "Main Menu"

def __init__(self,parent,id):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Window', size=(1000,700))
    panel=wx.Panel(self, -1)

    self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(100,100,100))
    self.Centre()
    self.Show()

    status=self.CreateStatusBar()

    menubar=wx.MenuBar()
    filemenu=wx.Menu()
    exitmenu = filemenu.Append(wx.NewId(),"Exit", "Exit Program")

    menubar.Append(filemenu,"File")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onExit, exitmenu)
    self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

    font1 = wx.Font(30, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False, u'Consolas')

    Text1=wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Rhythm Trainer", (10,15))
    Text1.SetFont(font1)
    Text1.SetForegroundColour('white')
    self.Show(True)

    btn1 = wx.Button(panel, label='Basic', pos=(100,200), size=(150, 50))
    btn1.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))

    btn1.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, window2)

    btn2 = wx.Button(panel, label='Advanced', pos=(100,270), size=(150, 50))
    btn2.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))

    btn3 = wx.Button(panel, label='Notations', pos=(100,340), size=(150, 50))
    btn3.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))

    btn4 = wx.Button(panel, label='Settings', pos=(100,410), size=(150, 50))
    btn4.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))

    btn5 = wx.Button(panel, label="Quit", pos=(820, 550), size=(150, 50))
    btn5.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, btn5)


def OnClick(self, event):
    self.Close()

def OnQuitButton(self, event):

    wx.Sleep(1)   
    self.Destroy()

def onExit(self, event):
     self.Destroy()

def newwindow(self, event):
     window2.show


class window2(wx.Frame):

title = "new Window"

def __init__(self,parent,id):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, id,'Window2', size=(1000,700))
    panel=wx.Panel(self, -1)

    self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(100,100,100))
    self.Centre()
    self.Show()


if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame=window(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all you want to do is hide the first frame and show the second, I wrote a tutorial on exactly that on my [blog](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/).

If you don't care if the first frame is still onscreen along with the second, then in your onClick method, you need to instantiate the second window and Show it. Something like this:

```
secondWindow = window2()
secondWindow.Show()
```

Do NOT close the first frame! That will just end the entire script. You only want to close that when you want the entire program to exit.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out and I'll be back with the results!

Comment: ahh thank you for that OnClick method! That made it work, with no errors. I was getting the __init__ argument error before. But I misplaced the secondWindow = Window 2 line. I'll definitely dwell more into your post for hiding the main menu though. That'll be needed! Cheers!

Comment: The main menu shouldn't be a part of the second window unless you've attached it to that window too.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that? I built the Main Window class, and then a second window class. So that on the main window, you press the button and it opens the second window.

Comment: Every frame has to have a SetMenuBar call, so you would have to specifically create a menu in each frame class and then attach it using SetMenuBar.

Comment: Ahh right, I get you now! I've gone further with the code at this time, so SetMenuBar is on each frame class. I'll update the code if you want to have a look?